# android maps first program

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

I'm going through the Google tutorial on mobile maps applications.
I manage to compile and run my application in a Android virtual phone:

5.4 FWVGA (480x854:mdpi).

When I actually start the application in the phone, I just get an empty map with a squared background (like geometry paper).

My feeling is that something is wrong here:

res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="blablabla"
/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellogooglemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So to be clear, how do I make my application connect to the internet and load the tiles?

thanks

jenia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you *have* got the Google API referenced in your project but you *haven't* got an API key - go [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/maps-api-signup) and use [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey) to guide you through making your project ready to use!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from checking that the Internet permission is granted in the manifest file (it´s something I use to forget when I start developing a new application), is the key you are using in the apiKey attribute of the MapView object specifically created for debugging purposes? If this is not the case, you won't be able to see the tiles, although you can still interact with the MapView.

Answer (score 0):

this link is a full solution:

(pt-br)
http://developerai.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/android-development-google-maps.html

dont forget

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

if u advanced developer and likes better apps, learn about:

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris